# theano - use external GPU only for ML and integrated GPU for display

Tags: gpu, theano, theano-cuda

I have a CPU with integrated GPU. I also have an external GPU that i have been using for ML. What i want is to use the integrated GPU only for display and dedicate the external GPU to NN training (in order to free some memory).

I have set at the BIOS the external GPU to be the primary GPU, but also to both be active. So they are both working. After i boot the system i can plug the monitor to any one of them and they both work.

The problem is that when i plug the monitor to the motherboard (integrated GPU) theano stops using the external GPU:

```
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): ERROR: Not using GPU. Initialisation of device gpu failed:
```

Is there a way to explicitly point theano to the external GPU? here is my the relevant part of my `.theanorc`:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar system to yours. For linux, installing `bumblebee` worked.

`sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia`
(adapt to your distro's package manager)

Then launch python via:
`optirun python`